# Angular Service test failing with $http mock in Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to test an Angular service which wraps my API calls. For testing I'm using `Jasmine` and `Karma`. My test looks like this:

```
describe('$http basic', function () {

  var ConcernService, $httpBackend, $scope;

  beforeEach(module('concernsApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
    ConcernService = $injector.get('ConcernService');
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    $scope =  $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();

    var projects = [{"id": 2, "title": "FooProject", "created_by": 1}, {"id": 5, "title": "BarProject", "created_by": 1}];

    $httpBackend.whenGET('http://localhost:8000/api/projects')
      .respond(projects);
 }));

 it('should return all projects', function () {

     ConcernService.list('projects')
        .then(function(data) {
          expect(data.length).toEqual(2);
     });

   $scope.$apply();
   $httpBackend.flush();

 });
```

This fails, giving me a `ConcernService` is undefined error.

I have tried injecting the `Concernservice` module directly into the test:

```
...

it('should return all projects', function () {

  inject(function(ConcernService) {

    ConcernService.list('projects')
      .then(function(data) {
        expect(data.length).toEqual(2);
    });

    $scope.$apply();
    $httpBackend.flush();

  });
});
```

But then I get a `modulerr` now, presumably from the unknown 'ConcernService` module.

What am I doing wrong here?

### Edit

```
var concernsApp = angular.module('concernsApp', [...]);

concernsApp.factory('ConcernService', function ($http, $q, $rootScope, dateFilter, globals) {
    ...
    var ConcernService = {
        list: function (items_url) {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $http({method: 'GET', 
                url: api_url + items_url}).
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    defer.resolve(data);
                }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    defer.reject(status);
                });
              return defer.promise;
        },
        ...
    };
    return ConcernService;
});
```

Comment: Where and how is the ConcernService defined?

Comment: Isn't it defined in the `$injector`?

Comment: Show us the code which defines the ConcernService.

Comment: Edit: show Service code.

Comment: 1.2.3: http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.3/angular.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I finally got to the bottom of the problem after walking away from it and coming back ;)

The solution was two-fold. I decided to change out the browser that Karma was running (I am on Debian and the easiest browser to hook up was FF). I changed to Chrome and all of a sudden I was getting better error messages. Where FF stated only that `ConcernService` was `undefined`, Chrome informed me that I had certain dependencies (local js files)  missing. Once I rectified those, all my tests passed!!!

Thankyou to all those who took the time to help me with this. I am posting this answer only ion the hope it maybe of use to others.

Answer (score 0):

we use this way for testing, try it:

```
beforeEach(module('concernsApp'));

beforeEach(inject(function (ConcernService) {
...
}));
```

Comment: Do you mean inject the Service outside of the `$injector`?